# Can´t add Firestore to Angular Project

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to add Firestore to my Angular Project. I already saw, when I only type in

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

the Installation failed. With

```
ng add @angular/fire@latest
```

I was able to add Firebase to the Angular App. Then a Wizard appears, where I wanted to select Firestore.
If I select Firestore, this error message appears:

```
The package @angular/fire@latest will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
√ Packages successfully installed.
UPDATE package.json (1231 bytes)
√ Packages installed successfully.
? What features would you like to setup? ng deploy -- hosting
√ firebase-tools installed globally.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:net'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\baumann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\portUtils.js
- C:\Users\baumann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\registry.js
- C:\Users\baumann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\controller.js
- C:\Users\baumann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\commandUtils.js
- C:\Users\baumann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\commands\database-get.js
- C:\Users\baumann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\commands\index.js
- C:\Users\baumann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\baumann\Desktop\markb.de\node_modules\@angular\fire\schematics\firebaseTools.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\baumann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\portUtils.js:6:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\baumann\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\emulator\\portUtils.js',
    'C:\\Users\\baumann\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\emulator\\registry.js',
    'C:\\Users\\baumann\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\emulator\\controller.js',
    'C:\\Users\\baumann\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\emulator\\commandUtils.js',
    'C:\\Users\\baumann\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\commands\\database-get.js',
    'C:\\Users\\baumann\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\commands\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\baumann\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\baumann\\Desktop\\markb.de\\node_modules\\@angular\\fire\\schematics\\firebaseTools.js'
  ]
}
```

This are  my versions:
`Angular CLI: 14.1.3 Node: 14.15.4 Package Manager: npm 6.14.10 OS: win32 x64`

I expected it installs Firebase/Firestore in my Angular Project

Comment: I guess you need to upgrade your nodejs version. at least to 16.x, or try to install older version of `@angular/fire` by `ng add @angular/fire@7.4`

Comment: I already deleted the Angular package.json package.lock.json and node_modules folder and tried to install the Angular Firesbase 7.4 version. It has also the same error described above

Comment: sorry for the late reply. the second option is to downgrade your node js version to 16 and try one more time. but this is risky and can be a reason for other problems

Comment: did not help me...